# Conditionaly required one or another field - Yup

Tags: node.js, backend, yup

I found this a bit complicated to explain and haven't found any solutions out there.

I have 3 fields in my schema. If field1 is false, field2 OR field3 are required. I tried this but it's not working:

```
    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
          field1: Yup.boolean().required(),
          fiel2: Yup.array().when(['field1', 'field3'], {
            is: (field1, field3) => !field1 && !field3,
            then: Yup.array().required(),
            otherwise: Yup.array(),
          }),
          field3: Yup.array().when(['field1', 'fiel2'], {
            is: (field1, fiel2) => !field1 && !fiel2,
            then: Yup.array().required(),
            otherwise: Yup.array(),
          }),
        });
```

Again, if field1 is false, one of the other 2 fields should be required.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `test` whenever it gets more complex:

```
yup.object().shape({
      field1: yup.string(),
      field2: yup.string().test({
        test: function (value) {
          const {field3, field1} = this.parent;
          if (field1 && !field3) return value != null;
          return true
        }
      }),
      field3: yup.string().test({
        test: function (value) {
          const {field1, field2} = this.parent;
          if (field1 && !field2) return value != null;
          return true
        }
      })
    });
```